# Collision of two sprite lists - SFML 2.0

Tags: c++, list, sprite, sfml

I am making a simple game in SFML 2 and it came smoothly so far. I created two sf::Sprite lists, one for enemies and one for lasers. The enemies spawn randomly off-screen and the lasers are created whenever input is given. I created a collision loop for both the lists and executed my code. There are no compile time and run time errors. The laser-enemy collision works fine for the first 3 to 4 enemies but after that, the collision does not occur. What might be causing this problem? Please help me on this. Thanks. Here's my code.

```
std::list<sf::Sprite>::iterator enemyit = enemy.begin(), next;
std::list<sf::Sprite>::iterator greenlaserit = greenlaser.begin(), reload;
while(enemyit != enemy.end())
{
    next = enemyit;
    next++;
    while(greenlaserit != greenlaser.end())
    {
        reload = greenlaserit;
        reload++;
        if(enemyit->getGlobalBounds().intersects(greenlaserit->getGlobalBounds()))
        {
                enemy.erase(enemyit);
                greenlaser.erase(greenlaserit);
                ++erased;
        }
        greenlaserit = reload;
    }
    enemyit = next;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be that you are doing a lot of iterator manipulation and that is likely to be where the problem is occurring.

If you can use c++11, I would suggest looking into the for each loop (http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html), to keep things really simple to read and understand (and thus, easier to debug).

You could do something like this:

```
    std::list<sf::Sprite> enemies;
    std::list<sf::Sprite> lasers;

    for (sf::Sprite enemy: enemies) {
       for (sf::Sprite laser : lasers) {
          if (enemy.getGlobalBounds().intersects(laser.getGlobalBounds())) {
            enemies.remove(enemy);
            lasers.remove(laser);
          }
       }
    }
```

Edit: otherwise, one method I have found for figuring out an iterator problem is stepping through it by hand.  I draw two rectangles with cells for each location, and keep track of the iterators and run through the logic step by step.  Before each iteration of your logic, write down your expected results.  Then go through it by hand and see if your results match your expectations.

Comment: I am not using C++11. But, I shall try your second method. Thank you.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you loop through a list by making a second variable (next, reload) and then immediately iterate it?  It seems to me that this will always skip the first element in the list.

Comment: That was to make sure that the iterator does not reach list::end(). It's crashing when I don't make use of a second variable.

Comment: Ok, I can see how that would happen.  You are immediately incrementing your iterators.  This is essentially an "off by one" error.  If you increment at the very end of the loop, you should be fine.  If you increment there, then the next line that is evaluated is the condition looking for the end of the list, so it would drop out of the loop then.